# jQuery datepicker not working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I am trying to implement jQuery datepicker in AngularJS.I followed the url `https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date` and did the same what was given. But I don't know where I'm lagging. I couldn't able to see the datepicker. I can see only the text box . Is there any other steps I should follow to implement jQuery datepicker in AngularJS other than this?

HTML :

```
<div class="to-show">
<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
<small>Date</small>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<input ui-date="dateOptions" name="DateOfBirth">
</div>
</div>
```

Controller :

```
myApp.controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.dateOptions = {
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        yearRange: '1900:-0'
    };
});
```

I have added the script files and CSS file as given
Could anyone please help me to resolve this?

Comment: have you added the dependency into your module?

Comment: try to check the z-index of the anctual datepicker, sometimes the problem is there

Comment: you are missing two closing `</div>`s

Comment: Actually I am getting the issue when the <div> are fine

Comment: I have added the dependency which I added in the code. In the router.js, I have added the ''ui.date'

Answer (score -1):

Have you added the "ng-app" attribute to your page?

Comment: Where should I want to add ng-app?

Comment: Hi Priya,  Well the docs recommend that the ng-app should be added somewhere close to the top of the page, i.e. the html or body elements. This is the link to the docs for [ng-app](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp).  If you don't have that attribute, then your controllers won't fire.